# EJB Injection Apache Wicket

Tags: apache, hibernate, jpa, ejb, wicket

So my question is more a "why does this work" kind of question rather than "this is broken, help me fix it".

One of the things I find I don't like about the Java enterprise stack is there are so many standards, and it's hard to say which one I should use (At least to me...I am new to Java EE although I have been programming for years.)

So I am implementing a toy application in Apache Wicket using JPA-Hibernate as my ORM/EntityManager and EJB for the injection of my data layer components (DAO design pattern).  I just struggled for the better part of two hours just trying to get dependency injection working.  So before I go any further, I have a [link](http://wicket.apache.org/guide/guide/jee.html#jee_1) that will be helpful.

This is ultimately the part I was missing.  Once I added the instantiation listener, I was at least not getting a null pointer error anymore.  However I was getting an error about the NamingContext being unable to find my DAO implementation.  Before I go any further let me supply my source code:

### DAO Impl

```
package com.trinary.persistence.dao;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

import com.trinary.persistence.entities.Lesson;

@Stateless(name="env/com.trinary.persistence.dao.LessonDAO")
public class LessonDAOImpl implements LessonDAO {
    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public void save(Lesson lesson) {
        em.persist(lesson);
    }

    @Override
    public Lesson find(long id) {
        return em.find(Lesson.class, id);
    }

    @Override
    public Lesson findByName(String name) {
        List<?> lessons = em.createNamedQuery("findLessonByName")
                .setParameter("lessonName", name)
                .getResultList();

        if (!lessons.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }

        return (Lesson)lessons.get(0);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Lesson> findAll() {
        List<?> lessons = em.createNamedQuery("findAll")
                .getResultList();

        if (lessons.isEmpty()) {
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }

        return (List<Lesson>)lessons;
    }
}
```

### Injecting Component

```
package com.trinary.panels;

import java.util.List;

import javax.ejb.EJB;

import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.basic.Label;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.list.ListItem;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.list.ListView;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.panel.Panel;
import org.apache.wicket.model.PropertyModel;

import com.trinary.persistence.dao.LessonDAO;
import com.trinary.persistence.entities.Lesson;

public class ContentPanel extends Panel {
    @EJB LessonDAO lessonDAO;

    public ContentPanel(String id) {
        super(id);

        List<Lesson> lessons = lessonDAO.findAll();

        add(new ListView<Lesson>("lessons", lessons) {
            @Override
            protected void populateItem(ListItem<Lesson> arg0) {
                arg0.add(new Label("name", new PropertyModel<Lesson>(arg0.getModel(), "name")));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

### Web Application

```
package com.trinary;

import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.WebPage;
import org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WebApplication;
import org.wicketstuff.javaee.injection.JavaEEComponentInjector;

import com.trinary.pages.HomePage;

/**
 * Application object for your web application.
 * If you want to run this application without deploying, run the Start class.
 * 
 * @see com.trinary.Start#main(String[])
 */
public class WicketApplication extends WebApplication {
    /**
     * @see org.apache.wicket.Application#getHomePage()
     */
    @Override
    public Class<? extends WebPage> getHomePage() {
        return HomePage.class;
    }

    /**
     * @see org.apache.wicket.Application#init()
     */
    @Override
    public void init() {
        super.init();
        getComponentInstantiationListeners().add(new JavaEEComponentInjector(this));        
    }
}
```

So this example works.  However if I don't name the DAO implementation (in the @Stateless annotation) in exactly the way I have it named...it won't work.  In the example from the link I provided, I can't get it to work the way they do.  I wonder if it has anything to do with the Web Container I am using (which is Wildfly/JBoss 8.0).

Can anyone explain or point me in the direction of an article that might help me understand why it works this way, but not the way it did in the example on Apache's page?  It's great that it works, but that is useless unless I know why it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `ComponentInstantiationListener` is called when a Wicket `Component` is created. You `Panel` is a `Component` and in the constructor of `Component` all `ComponentInstantiationListener`'s are called. The `JavaEEComponentInjector` checks for the `@EJB` annotation and injects where needed. You can use your Interface in your constructor and everywhere in your class except in or before the super() call like so:

```
public class DaoTest extends Panel{
    @EJB ISomeInterface someInterface;
    public DaoTest() {
        this(someInterface.getPanelId());
    }
    public DaoTest(String id) {
        super(id);
    }
}
```

Here the `ISomeInterface` instance is accessed before the constructor of `Component` so it's still null;

`@Stateless` is handled by your container and tells it that the bean does not maintain a state. This means that an instance can be given to anything that asks for it and that if the same session asks for it twice, it might get different instances of the bean. The name is used by the container to uniquely identify the bean. If you change the name and it doesn't work anymore then there might be some configuration of your container that's missing or inconsistent. Have you tried not giving a name at all?

Comment: Yes, if I don't give it a name, it won't work.  I haven't tried configuring the EJB container.  I kind of learned backwards.  I started all the way up at Groovy/Grails, then learned Spring (which makes IOC a cinch), and then I started learning Java EE components.  So I wasn't aware I had to configure JBoss's EJB container.

Thank you for the answer though, that clears that up =).  I just wish I knew why it doesn't work unless I name the component.